# Jailbroken iPad stuck on black screen - home button is non functional

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, ios

I just used taig to jailbreak an 8.3 pad.  All went well for a while and I was investigating and enjoying the freedom.  An app then crashed and now I have a black screen with what appears to be no way of restarting.

I should mention that my home button is not functional.

I could wait for the battery to run out but I'd rather not :)

I've tried the hold power for x seconds, tried it with the home but that doesn't do anything, there doesn't seem to be an option within iTunes and I'd rather not restore.

Is there an option for sending a reset signal without restore / home button?

thanks for any help.

Comment: You mean the home button is (hardware) broken? I read it as not functional because of the current software state... How do you even switch apps?